# Why is the court Infernal language question being voted closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

The standard five people have now voted to close [What does the court dialect of Infernal sound like?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87082/what-does-the-court-dialect-of-infernal-sound-like) as opinion-based.

I'm tempted to reopen it because it's directly asking for published material, and this doesn't appear to me to be any different from the situation of [What does Drow Speech sound like?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/8946) A comment to that effect didn't appear to result in any retracted votes or prevent the final vote from being cast.

So maybe I'm missing something right in front of my nose, or something more subtle, that is obvious to the close-voters and makes it **primarily opinion-based**. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7):

I was just looking at it, and was also tempted to reopen it on the same grounds. In fact, I'm going to, the "but the info in your comment" really isn't that crucial. I edited it in anyway.

While sure, we want people to explain the problem they're having, this seems like a pretty clear "I'm having trouble envisioning it, is there more canon on it" question that doesn't need the OP to start posting phonemes to answer.

Comment: Actually, I never got around to hitting a reopen after the changes were made and I forgot about this one.  Mea culpa.